# Magento 2 catalog_product_save_after when is triggered?

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2 the **event catalog_product_save_after** is triggered during import of products from csv file?

Thanks in advanced for any response.

Comment: Are you sure... or this `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after` ? or i think this `catalog_product_import_bunch_save_after`

Comment: I need to know if event catalog_product_save_after is triggered during import of product from csv, specifically for any products of csv file the above event is triggered?  Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as i can see on internet there is no `catalog_product_save_after` event exists in Magento2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to `CatalogImportExport/Model/Import/Product.php` and check `_saveProducts()` function you will see at the end they are dispatching `catalog_product_import_bunch_save_after` this event. May be this is getting called.

Comment: then the event catalog_product_save_after is not triggered during the import from csv but only when a produtcs is saved manually?

Comment: If you save it manually from admin panel then magento dispatch this event `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after` not `catalog_product_save_after`. Its a magento1 event not magento2.

Comment: Thank you very much Kingshuk Deb  , sorry but i have tested an observer using catalog_product_save_after event on magento 2 and it's able  to catch correctly the manually  save of a product.  
I wanted to understand if the event catalog_product_save_after is triggered  also during the import of product.    
I would be grateful if you could tell me if the event catalog_product_save_after or the controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after  is triggered when imports product from csv. Thank again.

Comment: Can you please let me know where `catalog_product_save_after` this event dispatched.

Comment: During creation/update of a product when i confirm the creation or update pressing save button.

Comment: I tested an observer with events:  **catalog_product_save_after** and ,**controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after** and during the import they didn't catch nothing. Thank  Kingshuk Deb  for the help.

Comment: Yes because as per my answer i think `catalog_product_import_bunch_save_after` this event does the work.

Answer (score 0):

As I found it will trigger on entity create or update and staging update or create scenarios.

```
Line 123 - Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Create
Line 110 - Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Update

public function execute($entity, $arguments = [])
    {
        $entityType = $this->typeResolver->resolve($entity);
        $metadata = $this->metadataPool->getMetadata($entityType);
        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnectionByName($metadata->getEntityConnectionName());
        $connection->beginTransaction();
        try {
            $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                'entity_manager_save_before',
                [
                    'entity_type' => $entityType,
                    'entity' => $entity
                ]
            );
            $this->eventManager->dispatchEntityEvent($entityType, 'save_before', ['entity' => $entity]);

            $entity = $this->getSequenceApplier()->apply($entity);

            $entity = $this->createMain->execute($entity, $arguments);
            $entity = $this->createAttributes->execute($entity, $arguments);
            $entity = $this->createExtensions->execute($entity, $arguments);
            $this->eventManager->dispatchEntityEvent($entityType, 'save_after', ['entity' => $entity]);
            $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                'entity_manager_save_after',
                [
                    'entity_type' => $entityType,
                    'entity' => $entity
                ]
            );
            $connection->commit();
        } catch (DuplicateException $e) {
            $connection->rollBack();
            throw new AlreadyExistsException(new Phrase('Unique constraint violation found'), $e);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $connection->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }
        return $entity;
    }
```

Cheers!